# When is it okay to take limits in inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> $a_n$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and $$a_n \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}a$$
> Show that $$\inf_n a_n \le a\le \sup_n a_n$$

I think it's okay to conclude that $$\inf_n a_n \le a_i\le \sup_n a_n$$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, can we just take $i\to\infty$ and conclude our result? **When is it okay/not okay** to take limits in inequalities like this? I haven't come across rules for the same before.

Comment: I think sandwich theorem / squeeze theorem can work here

Comment: I think the idea is that you are proving it is OK to take limits in inequalities like these.

Comment: You can take limits in *non-strict* inequalities (which is the case here).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Why not strict inequalities? I assume we can convert them to non-strict after taking the limit.

Comment: Fir styrict inequalities, there are trivial counterexample, e.g. $a_n=\dfrac 1n>0$ for all $n$, but its limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $ \inf a_n $ means $ \inf \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N$ and $ \sup a_n $ means $ \sup \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ . If yes, then

$$\inf a_n \le a_i\le \sup a_n$$

for all $i$ is trivial.

(Definition of $ \inf $ and $ \sup$)

This holds for each bounded sequence.

If $(a_n)$ is convergent to $a$, then we get

$$\inf a_n \le a\le \sup a_n$$

squeeze theorem !

Comment: Yes, I agree! My question is if it's safe to let $i$ approach infinity at this stage?